# Is this the correct way to mount share on Azure Storage with docker compose? [multi-containers with file share mounting]

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I tried to deploy multiple containers to Azure Container Instances with docker compose file.
My containers contain one server container and one postgressql db container. The server container is able to start up but the db container fail to start up (But I can't find any error message from the command line or on Azure)

[image]

The docker compose file is able to run locally, the only change I have made is on the "volumes:" part (last part of my docker compose yaml file) to mount the azure file share to the container for persistent storage and store some SQL scripts (in the sql file share) that will run when the database initialize (is this possible on Azure?).

I have already created the two file shares in my storage account

[image]

I am not sure if this mounting/running SQL during initialization is possible on Azure Container Instances.

Below is my yaml file

```
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: <my azure container registry>.azurecr.io/<my image name>
    # volumes:
    #   - ./app/:/code/app/
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
        <some environment variable here>
    depends_on:
      - db
 
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # Azure
      # - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # local
    environment:
        <some environment variable here>
    ports:
      - 5432:5432 
      
volumes:
    postgres-data:
      driver: azure_file
      driver_opts:
        share_name: postgres-data
        storage_account_name: <my storage account>
        storage_account_key: <my storage account access key>
    sql:
      driver: azure_file
      driver_opts:
        share_name: sql
        storage_account_name: <my storage account>
        storage_account_key: <my storage account access key>
```